# In the exterior of the ABCD square we construct the rhombus BCMN with BCM angle obtuse.How can i prove that A-C-M are collinear points?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples

> In the exterior of the ABCD square we construct the rhombus BCMN with BCM angle obtuse.Prove that A-C-M are collinear points

i need that result to another geometry problem and i don't have many ideas how can i proof that.

Comment: $A,C,M$ are colinear if and only if $\angle BCM=135^{\circ}$ as far as I can see. Are you sure you have it right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't because it's wrong. Take $\measuredangle BCM=100^{\circ}.$